# Can GCF node be invoked with flags

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I would like to try to use --experimental-modules flag in an attempt to streamline builds and bypass babel.

I've gone through the gcloud docs (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) and see some mention of starting functions with flags but these flags appear to be gcloud flags not flags passed to the node process

I would expect to be able to do something similar to piped args:
`gcloud functions deploy --runtime=nodejs10 -- --experimental-modules`

but I guess sensibly gcloud do not pass any old args along to the node process... so is there a way of starting node with this specific flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to change the runtime flags for the node process.  If you need more control over the way the process starts, I'd suggest taking a look at Google Cloud Run, as you are able to say exactly what goes into the docker image, and how exactly to invoke node when that image boots.

You will find that Cloud Run only lets you set up HTTP endpoints, so if you need one of the other product triggers available to Cloud Functions, you can arrange for a Cloud Functions to proxy the incoming data into Cloud Run for processing.

Comment: Currently using Pub/Sub triggers so will have to proxy but it's a good solution I think. And I assume Cloud Run will gradually get feature parity with Cloud Functions so probably only temporary. I guess the only downside would be potential cost implications of both cloud function and cloud run invocation on each trigger.

Comment: Actually my sub can be a push endppint... so I assume I can bypass Cloud Functions completely and push to whatever the unique Cloud Run endpoint is.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly arrange for pubsub messages to go directly to Cloud Run with some setup.